# sharing an http request call between tabs

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, request

I have multiple tabs in my ionic app. Two of those tabs currently make the same http get request. How do i make it such that the http request will be independent from those two tabs. I.e. When the http request is made but not finished and we switched to the other tab, the http request won't be interrupted and continue on fetching data.

Comment: as per my understanding, i think you want to cancel the http request on tab switching right?

Comment: no, the opposite. i want the http request to be shared between two tabs

Comment: you can create a common service